# Troubles with Syslog to Kiwi Syslog Server from PHP

Tags: php, windows, syslog

I'm trying to test an installation of Windows Kiwi Syslog Server by logging to it using the syslog function in PHP as follows:

```
syslog(LOG_WARNING, "test123");
```

The function returns *true* but the log doesn't show up in Kiwi which is running on the localhost. Is there any configuration required to enable syslog to work using PHP in Windows?

Comment: What has told you the technical support department of Kiwi Syslog Server about compatibility with PHP? What makes you believe it could work with Kiwi Syslog Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syslog() function call is a unix thing. According to the [php syslog manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php):

```
Notes
On Windows NT, the syslog service is emulated using the Event Log.
```

So it is unlikely that your messages will end up in kiwi syslog server unless it reads the EventLog.

Comment: Indeed. Windows sure does like to do things backwards. Thanks.